# Looping through the span and assigning the values to closest dropdown with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My objective is to get the value from span and assign the value to the dropdown on the same row.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bharatgillala/581hk9Ly/4/

```
<table id="gridviewInfo" runatr="server">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope=col>Available Boys.</th>
      <th scope=col>Already Selected Boy</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>
        <select id="sl1" class="judges">
          <option values="-1"></option>
          <option values="tom">tom</option>
          <option values="tom">harry</option>
          <option values="bob">bob</option>
        </select>
        <td>
          <span id="s2" class="spanclass">tom</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>
        <select id="sl2" class="judges">
          <option values="-1"></option>
          <option values="tom">tom</option>
          <option values="tom">harry</option>
          <option values="bob">bob</option>
        </select>
        <td>
          <span id="s1" class="spanclass">harry</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>
        <select id="sl3" class="judges">
          <option values="-1"></option>
          <option values="tom">tom</option>
          <option values="tom">harry</option>
          <option values="bob">bob</option>
        </select>
        <td>
          <span id="s3" class="spanclass"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My objective is to loop through all the spans and if there is any text, get the text and assign the text to the closest dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already [answered that for you yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747922/validate-the-dom-using-jquery/32748494#32748494). The code is fully commented below:

```js
(function(d) {
  // when all the DOMElements are already loaded into the document
  d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // gets the generated table, and get all the dropdownlists inside it
    var table = document.getElementById('gridviewInfo'),
        ddls = [].slice.call(table.querySelectorAll('.judges'));

    // loop through the dropdownlists
    ddls.forEach(function(ddl, i) {
      // get the label inside the last td
      var lbl = ddl.parentNode.parentNode.lastElementChild.firstElementChild;

      // change the dropdownlist selectedvalue to the label text
      ddl.value = lbl.textContent.trim();
    });
  });
})(document);
```

```html
<table id="gridviewInfo" runatr="server">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope=col>Available Boys.</th>
      <th scope=col>Already Selected Boy</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>
        <select id="sl1" class="judges">
          <option value="-1"></option>
          <option value="tom">tom</option>
          <option value="harry">harry</option>
          <option value="bob">bob</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="s2" class="spanclass">tom</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>
        <select id="sl2" class="judges">
          <option value="-1"></option>
          <option value="tom">tom</option>
          <option value="harry">harry</option>
          <option value="bob">bob</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="s1" class="spanclass">harry</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" align=left>
        <select id="sl3" class="judges">
          <option value="-1"></option>
          <option value="tom">tom</option>
          <option value="harry">harry</option>
          <option value="bob">bob</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="s3" class="spanclass"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/581hk9Ly/6/

---

And if you want [a jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/581hk9Ly/9/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.spanclass').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.judges').val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: Darn bet me to it. Can I just add that your markup is invalid - you're missing closing </td> tags after your selects.

Comment: Don't forget to change the "values" attribute of the option elements to "value" - there is no such thing as "values".

Comment: @CainBot thanks! I've edited my answer! (btw, the HTML code was copied from the question, so I didn't even look at it hehe)

Comment: @HaukurHaf thanks! I've edited my answer! (btw, same as the comment above)

Comment: @Buzinas - I meant to edit and state that when I said you're I meant the OP =)